# Fastest way to access a row in sqlite using a row number

Tags: sqlite

Sqlite doesn't have a row number function. My database however could have several thousands of records. I need to sort a table based upon a date (the date field is actually an INTEGER) and then return a specific range of rows. So if I wanted all the rows from 600 to 800, I need to somehow create a row number and limit the results to fall within my desired range. I cannot use RowID or any auto-incremented ID field because all the data is inserted with random dates. The closest I can get is this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (ID INTEGER, Name TEXT, DateRecorded INTEGER);

Insert Into Test (ID, Name, DateRecorded) Values (5,'fox', 400);
Insert Into Test (ID, Name, DateRecorded) Values (1,'rabbit', 100);
Insert Into Test (ID, Name, DateRecorded) Values (10,'ant', 800);
Insert Into Test (ID, Name, DateRecorded) Values (8,'deer', 300);
Insert Into Test (ID, Name, DateRecorded) Values (6,'bear', 200);

SELECT ID,
       Name,
       DateRecorded,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Test AS t2
        WHERE t2.DateRecorded > t1.DateRecorded) AS RowNum
FROM Test AS t1
where RowNum > 2
ORDER BY DateRecorded Desc;
```

This will work except it's really ugly. The Select Count(*) will result in carrying out that Select statement for every row encountered. So if I have several thousands of rows, that will be a very poor performance.

Comment: Sqlite has very nice documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [LIMIT/OFFSET clauses](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) are for:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
ORDER BY DateRecorded DESC
LIMIT 200 OFFSET 600
```